# How to completely remove hyperledger fabric from ubuntu?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am learning hyperledger fabric and installed an old version. I want to delete it completely and start from the begining.

Comment: How did you installed it? Using docker? Just delete the whole folder will do.,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [install instructions](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.4/install.html#download-fabric-samples-docker-images-and-binaries) download some Git repositories to a directory of your choice. Delete everything downloaded to whichever directory you chose.

Docker images for the version of Fabric you installed will have been downloaded (with Docker repository names beginning "**hyperledger/**"). Running a Fabric network (such as the *test-network* included in the samples) will create Docker containers from those images, and new Docker images and associated containers for chaincode (with names beginning "**dev-**"). For example:

```
% docker images --format "{{.Repository}}"

dev-peer0.org2.example.com-basic_1.0-6f5b7f9a66c5e564f16e35d749e65f21664215993a5c715a82150f7e7c403987-dd01284be4ea7c043c34f88df348ff91e20c89d83e1b318e30b6ad1ddb1fdf38
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-basic_1.0-6f5b7f9a66c5e564f16e35d749e65f21664215993a5c715a82150f7e7c403987-c5d394c5ddd6a7771991f6fec4e5e817f9ffc7c44055b7ae94586a17ed6e9a43
hyperledger/fabric-tools
hyperledger/fabric-peer
hyperledger/fabric-orderer
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv
hyperledger/fabric-baseos
hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv
hyperledger/fabric-ca
```

Bring down any running Fabric Docker networks, then remove all Fabric Docker containers and images.

Comment: Worked! Thank You!